# Hibernate+Oracle+Clob: Content of attributes get switched

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, clob

Has anyone heard of this error before:

I have a Java 5 application, that uses Hibernate 3.3.2 to access an Oracle Database 10g, the JDBC driver is the Oracle light driver version 10.2.0.4.0 (the most recent version, I think).
The database access happens during a transaction that is managed via the AOP-tools of spring.
There is one database table mapped to one Java entity, the mapping is done via annotations. There are two attributes in this entity that are CLOB in the database. They are annotated according to JPA with "Lob" and are Java Strings. Everthing works fine unless both attributes have values with more than 4000 characters: After the commit the values are switched on the database, that is attribute A contains the value of attribute B and vice versa.

This is not a joke!

The Eclipse debugger tells me that the Java entity has the correct values until the transaktion closes (I did not debug into the spring transaction handling).
This error does not occur if both Clobs are annotated with the Hibernate annotation 'Type(type = "clob")' (in which case they have to be of the type java.sql.Clob and not String, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution to the problem: The SQL-dialect was wrong, someone set it to Oracle9 instead of the correct version, which is this:

name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"

Setting the correct SQL-dialect solves the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but could you try to set the connection property `SetBigStringTryClob` to `true` (see [How To Handle CLOBs Easily in JDBC?](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/clob10g/handlingclobsinoraclejdbc10g.html#how1)).

If you are using Spring, something like this:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's supposed to fix errors with more than 32kB in a CLOB-Attribute, I did try that to no avail. There are several questions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere about problems with one single CLOB attribute and content over 4000 characters or more. I hope I found them all :-) Note that my problem occurs only when at least two attributes have more than 4000 characters.

Comment: @Tim TBH, this was more a shot in the dark. Actually, your case is really strange (and I wonder *who* is swapping the values) and smells like a nasty bug somewhere. Adding this question to my favorite to follow this story.

Comment: My guess is that a) CLOB values need a special handling when containing more than 4000 characters, and b) either Hibernate or the Oracle JDBC driver has an error that switches the values if there is more than one that needs this extra handling. But I cannot afford the time to debug both, and I did not find a similar bug in the Hibernate bug DB. (I can't simply upgrade Hibernate, because the software is used in production and changing the whole Hibernate distribution would necessitate a thorough test of the whole software).

Comment: @Tim a) Yes, which is why I suggested to try the above option b) I would run a simple JDBC test to see how the JDBC driver behave with raw JDBC code. If you reproduce the problem, then you'll know where it is :)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. Two CLOB on a table. On the insert only one is set and everything is fine. On the update I set the second one and after commit the values on table are swapped. Both contains more than 4000 characters. Debugged and the values on the bean are correct.
The sad thing is that i have already org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect in my properties.
(Hibernate version 4.2.2.Final)

//UPDATE
for the moment as a workaround I have set the first column as **updatable=false** in the JPA annotation so that during the generation of the update query by hibernate there is only one CLOB column now. I can do this as that in this particular case I don't need to change the value after the insert, but it's not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing  that worked for us was to use hql queries for the update. Each query updated a single CLOB (so we needed two separate queries):

```
Query query = em.createQuery("update SomeTable as someTable set value = :value where id = :id");
query.setParameter("value", value);
query.setParameter("id", id);
if (query.executeUpdate() != 1) {
    throw new Exception("Value update had no effect");
}
```